# OpenGL program with tensorflow C++ gives failed call to cuInit : CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY

Tags: c++, opengl, tensorflow

I have trained a model with no issues using tensorflow on python. I am now trying to integrate inference for this model into a pre-existing OpenGL enabled software. However, I get a `CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY` during `cuInit` (that is, even earlier than loading the model, just at session creation). It does seem, that OpenGL has taken some MiBs of memory (around 300 MB), as shown by `gpustat` or `nvidia-smi`.

Is it possible there is a clash as both TF and OpenGL are trying to access/allocate the GPU memory? Has anyone encountered this problem before? Most references I found googling around are at model loading time, not at session/CUDA initialization. Is this completely unrelated to OpenGL and I am just barking up the wrong tree? A simple TF C++ inference example works. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the tensorflow logging output, for completeness:

```
2018-01-08 12:11:38.321136: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-01-08 12:11:38.379100: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:406] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-01-08 12:11:38.379388: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:158] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: rosenblatt
2018-01-08 12:11:38.379413: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:165] hostname: rosenblatt
2018-01-08 12:11:38.379508: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] libcuda reported version is: 384.98.0
2018-01-08 12:11:38.380425: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:369] driver version file contents: """NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  384.98  Thu Oct 26 15:16:01 PDT 2017 GCC version:  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5)"""
2018-01-08 12:11:38.380481: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:193] kernel reported version is: 384.98.0
2018-01-08 12:11:38.380497: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:300] kernel version seems to match DSO: 384.98.0
```

**EDIT:** Removing all references to OpenGL resulted in the same problem, so it has nothing to do with a *clash* between the libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem was the use of the sanitizer in the debug version of the binary. The release version, or the debug version with no sanitizer work as expected.